# Is there a reliable path to specific device events?

Tags: udev, devices, proc, input, sysfs

I'm running ubuntu linux and I have a bluetooth mouse that I would like to capture evdev events from. The problem is that the event device can potentially be different any time I connect the mouse: sometimes it's `/dev/input/event17`, sometimes `/dev/input/event16`, etc.

`/dev/input/by-id` and `/dev/input/by-path` aren't getting populated for this device. I've seen solutions that involve parsing /proc/bus/input/devices to find the event number, but I feel like there has to be an easier way. Isn't there a symlink out in /proc or /sys that will always point to the events for a specific device? Or Maybe some udev rule that I could configure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `udevadm info` to query device attributes, then creat udev rule which would create symlink in `/dev/` to easy access the device by your custom name. See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udev#udev_rule_example